# Trying to open an .exe file with a .txt file as an argument using Process.Start()

Tags: vb.net, process.start

I have an .exe file which takes in a .txt file as an argument. However, I cant make it work using the code below in vb.net. It works when I run the .exe with cmd with the text file.

```
Dim a As New ProcessStartInfo
a.FileName = "C:\Users\Asim Rahman\Desktop\Project Input Files\DirectStiffness.exe"
a.Arguments = "C:\Users\Asim Rahman\Desktop\Project Input Files\HW3A.txt"
a.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized
Process.Start(a)
```

I have also tried opening the program and the file in numerous other ways, but I have failed to make it work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Why you have a quote before Process? Can you please post a meaningful bit of your code?

Comment: Dim a As New ProcessStartInfo
        a.FileName = "C:\Users\Asim Rahman\Desktop\Project Input Files\DirectStiffness.exe"
        a.Arguments = "C:\Users\Asim Rahman\Desktop\Project Input Files\HW3A.txt"
        a.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized
        Process.Start(a)

Comment: This is what I have done now, but it still says the same thing. File could not be opened. @varocarbas

Comment: You have to surround with quotes paths containing spaces (and, ideally, any one) when using the CMD, but by using the code as you are doing it, it seems to work fine either way. Perhaps your problem has to do with privileges: you might be executing the CMD with elevated rights (as admin) and that's why it works in this way; otherwise, both options (CMD and your code) should deliver the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that your exe file finds your text file by way of input args.
But your full path to the text file contains spaces and this breaks your args parameters to more than one element.
Your program refers to the first argument that is an incomplete path.

```
args[0] = "C:\users\asim" 
.....
```

and so on for every space present in your pathname to the txt file.

A simple solution is to specify the [WorkingDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx) and remove the full path from the arguments

```
Dim a As New ProcessStartInfo
a.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Users\Asim Rahman\Desktop\Project Input Files"
a.FileName = "DirectStiffness.exe"
a.Arguments = "HW3A.txt"
a.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized
Process.Start(a)
```

Comment: It is curious. I tested these conditions (with spaces in both file name and directory name) and it worked fine in its original configuration (without surrounding quotes and without specifying the working directory)! At least in .NET 4.0. But well... your fixed the OP's problem and thus +1 for you :)

Comment: This only works if you have files, right? Assume you wanted to pass another parameter, that doesn't refer to a file - in that case you'd need to double quote. But as this solves the original question: +1

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that you need to quote the file name you pass as argument, because it contains spaces. If you don't wrap it in double quotes, your application will get the following parameters seperately:

> C:\Users\Asim
>   Rahman\Desktop\Project
>   Input
>   Files\HW3A.txt

Try this:

**C# version**

```
a.Arguments = @"\"C:\Users\Asim Rahman\Desktop\Project Input Files\HW3A.txt\"";
```

**VB version**

```
a.Arguments = """C:\Users\Asim Rahman\Desktop\Project Input Files\HW3A.txt"""
```

Comment: This returns a syntax error, let me try changing the folder name

Comment: This is C#. Not all what works in C# works in VB. In VB you have to repeat quotes. In any case, I tested it and there seems to not be any need to surround the argument with quotes (even when spaces are present in the name).

Comment: Sorry, I wrote C# as my VB.NET is not that fluent.

Comment: The VB.NET version is very easy: """C:\Users\Asim Rahman\Desktop\Project Input Files\HW3A.txt""" (quotes twice + ending and starting quotes). But, as commented in Steve's answer, I tested these conditions in .NET 4.0 and worked fine without quotes/Working directory?!

Comment: Well, all I know is that when you want to pass a parameter to a program you need to enclose it in double quotes if it contains spaces. That's a rule :-)

Comment: I know, I know but VB.NET is very flexible with rules in general :) It has been somehow surprising to me because I am always using the quoting rule... (you have to add one quote more at the start and and at the end -> three quotes at each end: two to simulate a quote + starting/ending one)

Comment: Well, that is not a VB rule, it's an OS rule. If you pass parameters to a process you need to double quote it if it contains spaces.

Comment: But how you know what VB does? The program will surely pass quotes at the end but, apparently, VB surrounds automatically your inputs (= the code you write) with quotes... The magic of VB.NET! every time surprising! :) Please, fix the quoting issue such that I can +1 this answer.

Comment: VB may not automatically quote the string, as otherwise you'd not be able to pass multiple parameters without quotes. Could it be that you're mixing up things the VB.NET development environment does automatically as opposed to what the .NET Framework does?

Comment: Well... there are more or less easy work-arounds for that (spliting the inputs by " " and quoting each chunk). But I cannot be sure: as said, I am always quoting the arguments. On the other hand, there is not too much to argue against what actually works/not. You can do the test yourself: open a new VB.NET project in .NET 4.0, write the original OP's code and use a program like explorer.exe to open paths with spaces on it (in both name of the file and directory) and you would see that it works without quoting...